# Varnish W3C like format logging

Tags: caching, logging, reverse-proxy, varnish

I'm new to varnish and I'm setting up for some of the websites I manage.

One of the difficulties I'm having is to debug it. I know that there's varnishlog, but it would be really helpful to have something similar to W3C logging for all request served by varnish. In addition to standard fields, there will be one extra field to show if the request was served from cache, from back-end, etc.

Is there something like this or a way to have this kind of log?

Thanx,
Albert

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this, the solution is varnishncsa